# Randomised bank accounts

Tags: society

One morning, everyone wakes up and finds that the balance in their bank account has changed. In some cases, it's gone down. In others, it's gone up, a lot. A few people even find that they don't appear to have been affected by this. However, most company accounts have also been affected.

After some effort, someone figures out that all the bank balances have been randomised - it's like someone just pulled balances and accounts out of a hat and stuck them together. There isn't any pattern to this, so it doesn't seem to be targeted - it's entirely luck as to whether you (or your company) end up richer, poorer, or about the same as before.

However, other than your memories and environment (e.g. you're in a mansion, so probably were doing ok...), there is no way to prove which balance was previously yours. Backup data has also been altered to be consistent. Every detail apart from the associated names is accurate. If account 123 sent money to account 456, that's still recorded, but account 123 probably belongs to someone other than expected.

What would the overall change in wealth distribution?

I suspect there will be a bias towards getting poorer, with a few stand out cases of someone getting immensely rich. A lot of people wouldn't be affected - anyone without a bank account- but these will probably be disproportionately poorer, since it's harder to be rich without one.

Note: the technical ability to do this is out of scope (short answer: in our world, you probably can't!)

Comment: I would check the dystopic worldbuiling in  Mr Robot tv series where the worlds biggest conglomerate(this includes the finance sector) gets totally blacked out(encrypted entirely with back up data centers sabotaged) and no records of ownership before the hack remain.

Comment: Does this affect only bank balances, or property and investments more generally? Very wealthy people are likely to have most of their money in shares, bonds, real estate, etc. rather than as cash in a bank account. In the case of Average Jane Citizen, does she still own her house? Her car? Her pension fund?

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Just bank (building society/credit union/etc) accounts. If you have shares and so on, they're still yours

Comment: Side note: This is actually somewhat plausible.  One of the major database systems in use has an "implicit" key known as the "Relative Record Number", essentially the index of the row from the start of the file.  The problem is that's _exactly_ what it is, and if the table is re-organized (there's a command for that), the RRN changes; note however, that this is usually only done if there's large gaps from record deletions, which is unusual in a banking scenario.  Note too that doing this among the entire database would result in odd errors (ie, transactions don't match summed amounts).

Comment: If it is a shuffle 1/2 will be less and 1/2 will be more.

Comment: @Paparazzi: Not only that, but at least the "previously rich(er)" ones (and companies) will try to get their accounts back using money spending schemes (such as regular expenses or dips when buying something expensive, e.g. their new sports car) to prove their ownership. The history is still recorded, just with wrong names!

Comment: @hoffmale Why are you addressing me?

Comment: Note that if this includes *business* bank accounts, then quite a lot of businesses will have instant cashflow problems and be driven out of business. Everyone ends up worse off.

Comment: What about my checkbook? Granted, I only use the thing to pay my rent, but they gave me several books worth of checks when I opened my account. Those have my name, address, account number, and routing number on them.

Comment: @Paparazzi it would only be half with an equal distribution to start with. More likely, the distribution is a "long tail" graph, or tall pyramid.  Many more folks (in number) have a "below average" (average = mathematical mean) balance due to the few *very* *very* high balances. The very few high balance accounts will end up worse, but the many low ones could change relatively little, or all go up.  It won't be "half less and half more". (E.g. balances 1,2,3,4,5,1000 - rotate each owner 1 account to the right. 5 of 6 people get more money, and only 1 loses (a lot) of money)

Comment: @JesseM but account 123 probably belongs to someone other than expected

Comment: " it's entirely luck" Except that it isn't. The poorer population likely got richer, and the rich population likely got poorer.

Comment: @JesseM No, you're making an arbitrary construction to try to prove your point. To see this in action, rotate each owner 1 account to the left instead - then 5 of 6 people get less money.

Comment: So, what about people like me who still get and keep paper account statements?  Did all the paper get changed too?  If not then there might be enough information to reverse at least some of the changes.

Comment: This seems a bit contrived. Any kind of paper trail - bills, debit cards etc, will soon prove who owned what account. Even if you randomised the balance the careful people who keep all their bank statements would have records of what their balance should be.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If the change affects *bank accounts* only, the results might be surprisingly modest. Putting cash in a bank account is a very poor investment, especially with interest rates as low as they currently are. Most wealthy people will have most of their money in stocks, bonds, real estate and the like, perhaps with "only" \$100,000 or so in cash at any given time. While for most of us a sudden windfall of $100,000 would be very welcome, it doesn't make you filthy rich.

Most of the wealth redistribution would take place at the middle and bottom end of the scale. The wealthy are relatively few in number, but there are many people with \$10,000 or so in cash savings, and a great many others with little or none. A lot of the former would suddenly have no savings, and many of the latter would receive a windfall. There would be more losers than winners: In the USA, 69% of the population [have less than \$1000 in savings](https://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/03/how-much-americans-at-every-age-have-in-their-savings-accounts.html).

A few things worth noting:

- Savings do not correlate exactly with income; many well-paid middle-class people have large credit card debts and minimal savings.
- Many bank accounts are held by businesses, charities, government departments, and other organisations. If they were affected, a lot of businesses might find themselves with severe cash flow problems.
- A very roughly analagous situation occurred with [privatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatization_in_Russia) in Russia in the 1990s, in which shares in state-owned industries were distributed among the population. A few individuals became very wealthy by buying up shares at a fraction of their real value.

This would probably become a serious political issue for the government. Would it:

- Order banks to honour the account records, even though they conflict with people's memories?
- Somehow attempt to reinstate the distribution of wealth people remember?
- Take drastic action like resetting the entire banking system from zero, perhaps giving *everyone* exactly the same amount of cash as a starting point?

Comment: Keep in mind, this is not just personal banks accounts, corporations are messed up too. The banks are corporations themselves, so their mutual correspondent accounts and accounts with central banks are also affected. Somebody would end up with 100,000,000 in a bank account, but the bank itself may have just 10,000 in liquid, non-cash assets.

Comment: "A lot of the former would suddenly have no savings, and many of the latter would receive a windfall. There would be more losers than winners". Surely among a group defined to exclude the larger bank balances, there will (in all probability) be more winners than losers, by definition of "shuffle randomly"?

Comment: @SteveJessop The distribution of balances is exactly the same before and after, only the names have changed. Surely there are exactly as many winners as losers?

Comment: "There would be more losers than winners" Not true. On average, there will be the same number of winners as losers. A permutation is a set of instructions of the form "Give A's account to B." given any permutation of the people, you can make the "opposite" permutation by changing each instruction to "Give B's account to A." If a permutation had X winners and Y losers, the opposite permutation (which is equally likely to be generated) has Y winners and X losers so the average number of winners is equal to the average number of losers. (cc @JollyJoker)

Comment: Note, though, that it's possible to have nearly everybody win: line up the people in order of bank balance and give each person the account of the person ahead of them in the line, except that the richest person becomes the poorest. Everybody but them wins.

Comment: @DavidRicherby One potential issue to create more winners than losers is if the rich minority has more bank accounts per person than the poor majority.

Comment: @JollyJoker: well, it seemed to me that in that sentence Royal was talking about "many people with \$10,000 or so in cash savings, and a great many others with little or none", not about the whole population. It seems to be hopelessly ambiguous, if Royal thinks it goes down, I think it goes up, and you think it stays the same!

Comment: @Patrick: because if you talk about a what happens to a specific subset of the population, you get a different answer within that subset from what you get for the whole population.

Answer (score 27):

**If you read Clancy, you know Ryan's Law: If it wasn't written down, *it didn't happen***.  So if all written records say a thing, then it doesn't matter what everyone *thinks*.

However if the magic does not go so far as to altering *paper* records and PDFs sitting on hard drives and the like, then it becomes a matter for whatever deposit insurance your nation/world provides.   Once it's accepted that this glitch did an unintended redistribution of wealth: a *saver* who can document that their bank account had between 61,000 and 66,000 quid for the last several years, can expect a £61,000 payout from deposit insurance.  This would not help the rich so much; most deposit insurance is capped, e.g. US FDIC at $250,000. *Non-savers* who had nothing on average for years and suddenly have a million bucks - it will be difficult to pursue them if *they alone possess* the only records of their history and they want to hide unearned gains (not leasst from the tax man).

But *non-savers* will tend to lose it.  Savings is not innate; it requires a friendly environment *(which we presume if in a ”world" where most citizens have bank accounts)*, luck, and education to avoid the pitfalls of having money.  The effects of this lack are seen by the fate of lottery winners.  Left to themselves, they are [predated upon aggressively](http://amzn.to/2hGJ4AQ) and tend to lose it.  Good counseling by government or NGOs can [significantly improve things.](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2016/01/lottery-winners-research/423543/) **The question is how this counseling will *reach* savings-scramble winners** if they are hiding.

(and of course a person with good circumstance and skills *already* does well with windfalls).

The same applies to now-broke *savers*: Their circumstances will allow, and their habits will motivate, them to resume saving. Their accounts will build back up over time.

So there are your four likelihoods:

- started non-saver, account empty - no change
- started saver, account has money - no change
- started non-saver, now full account - tend to lose it.
- started saver, now empty account - tend to continue saving.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. The difficulty comes from a conflict between physical environment (living in a dingy flat) and a bank account with millions in.

Comment: Your link says almost the exact opposite of your claim about lottery winners: *"American lottery winners did not typically quit their jobs and spend lavishly."* It is not the case that all or even most poor people are irresponsible with money.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I have no link, but the same underlying principle applies.  People's ability to **have** money is at a certain level.  It's not drastically altered by giving them more money or taking money away.  (It can be altered in other ways, but it first must be recognized as a quality of the *person,* not the bank account.)

Comment: @Wildcard: You seem to be saying modern society is a pure [meritocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meritocracy#Social_Darwinism), operating by [Social Darwinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Darwinism). This is simply not true. As a counterpoint, I recommend [this post](http://whatever.scalzi.com/2005/09/03/being-poor/) by the SF author John Scalzi.

Comment: @RoyalCanadian I think what he was getting at was that in general, people who don't have some sort of structure in place to control money literally cannot control their spending.  If you read on, it states that future generations didn't benefit - the money doesn't go to improving their lot in life in the long term, and that while the chances of going bankrupt in the first few years was reduced, there was a greater chance of going bankrupt in the years following (presumably due to increased spending (due to having money) and then the money running out.

Comment: @Matthew You may want to read the book *The Millionaire Next Door*. To summarize for the purposes of this discussion, the person who lives in a modest home, has a worn but still reliable vehicle, etc., is far more likely to have a high net worth than the person who lives in a mansion and trades vehicles for new from the factory every 2-3 years, simply because the expenses of the former person are lower. Unless you *need* the facade in order to maintain your income (which you practically never do, beyond the utter basics), lower expenses typically means higher net worth.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit **Being poor is trusting the DM when he says you rolled a 1 again**.  I don't think either wildcard or myself is trying to turn it into an ideological discussion nor endorse one system over another.  I am sticking to the practical/real world, where idealized systems don't work and effective systems are a well-engineered blend.  Rich people often go bust -  and are momentarily as broke as poor people. What happens next defines the difference, and that is largely a function of habit and training.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Try the book ["Money for Nothing"](http://amzn.to/2hGJ4AQ) for the more cautionary tale.  As for rich people's stories, that is obviously a secret. If I told you, they'd kill us both. Seriously, that is what everyone thinks, isn't it?  Truth be told, the rich are happy to share, but no one wants to listen.  Andrew Carnegie decided to share the "secrets" with author Napoleon Hill, the book is called ["Think and Grow Rich"](http://amzn.to/2wEA9SY) .

Comment: Habit. Training. Thinking. As far as I can tell, the argument boils down to "rich people are smart, poor people are stupid, wider socioeconomic factors are irrelevant." If you really believe that, there's no point in continuing this discussion.

Comment: Downvoted for the conclusion, although the first couple paragraphs are really good. —But maybe there's a disconnect here: do you Harper consider *yourself* one of the good ones, those who are naturally rich by merit and will never stay poor long? Or do you consider yourself one of "those people," the deserving poor who waste every chance they're given? After all, in some contexts a person making \$80,000 a year is "rich", and in other contexts he's "poor". In the United States, the 99th percentile of annual salaries is \$400,000. If you're below that, you might actually be part of "the 99%"!

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit SE is not a discussion forum. Most people have very strong preconceptions about money - *in which they are so inculcated* that they are literally incapable of accurately parsing a message which is orthagonal to it.  These preconceptions are molded by family, and have that same strength. Do not for a minute think it's "easy" to climb out of that ideological gravity well. It's a big part of **socio**economic forces you mention.  "As far as I can tell"... "no point continuing" - both true, you literally cannot understand what I am saying.

Comment: rich and poor are not absolute. they're relative terms. there are not just four possibilities.

Comment: @Octopus   Most constructive criticism yet.  You're right.  I got too stuck in "Rich Dad, Poor Dad" model and made it about rich/poor, which caused "a lot of fuss".  Actually what is on-topic is savers/non-savers.  Major edit along those lines and to try to stop inferences from being made which were never intended.

Comment: @Quuxplusone revised.  Your hate language is inappropriate but it made me realize I was also more judgmental than the answer required.

Comment: @Quuxplusone The OP didn't specify whether this was global or limited to one country, like the USA. Note that globally, the top 1% of incomes starts at [USD $32,400](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/050615/are-you-top-one-percent-world.asp).

Comment: @JoelHarmon: Very good point! This specific *answer* seemed to be limited to at least the First World, though, and presumably the USA, because of the references to the FDIC. I mean if the context is the *world*, then this answer is basically starting with the assumption that if anyone *in the world* is poor it's because they're incapable/unintelligent/lazy (or a "non-saver", in the new math) — that if you gave them a few million dollars tomorrow, they'd just go spend it all on drugs, or whatever starving Africans do for fun, and then they'd all be poor and the USA would be rich again.

Comment: @Quuxplusone When I change my words, I intend to change my meaning.  Because my original words were wrong, and judgmental in a way I did not intend. **I changed my meaning** specifically because of what you said and you should be taking credit for that.  The scope of the question *is the first world* since the question presumes most people have bank accounts.  What will it take to change your downvote? Or do you just need to hate?

Comment: Well, I think this answer is just fundamentally *factually incorrect*, so I'm unlikely to upvote it unless you change it out of all resemblance to *your* beliefs. That's fine. That's how SO works. :) But one easy improvement to make would be to remove or source your lottery-winner claim. As RCB said in comment #2, your current link goes to an article claiming things like "A study of U.S. lottery winners from the 1980s found that winning a lot of money (rather than just a little bit) increased reported savings rates, and large winners tended to scale back on the number of hours they worked."

Comment: I don't get the hate for this answer, it's a very good answer. It does not say "all poor people are poor because they are stupid", it says "a lot of people who manage to stay wealthy do so because they know how to manage their finances". It doesn't mean the wealthy people who manage their finances well are smart or that poor people are unintelligent, that's not what the answer is saying. What the answer is saying is that people will resume their previous habits and that will determine whether they manage to hold on to their newfound wealth or not.

Comment: Search-and-replacing the word "poor" with "non-saver" does *not* change your meaning; it changes the *words* you use to express it. This isn't about "hate" and it *certainly* isn't about "hate language". I don't hate your language or your beliefs. I just think that *the premise on which this answer is based is factually incorrect* and therefore this is not a realistic answer to the OP's question. This answer "works" only in a world that, in my opinion, doesn't resemble the real world. (Obviously you disagree, or you wouldn't have written it. This is fine.)

Comment: @Pharap in all fairness I wrote the first cut in haste, and it reflected my bias toward focusing on *volitional* factors, because I have been trained to focus on things I *can* change not things I cannot.  I never meant to create any of the judgmentalism that quix, royal and others inferred, however in hindsight, they were not unreasaonable for inferring it.

Comment: @Quuxplusone massive edit, in which I reduce volition to a footnote.  I'm here to write answers, and I don't have any axe to grind about volition vs circumstance here.  I feel the Atlantic article is distorted because it mostly considers cases where the government intervenes by providing counseling and support. When that is not present, it's uglier.     Speaking of volition, when I change my words, **I mean to change my meaning**, so don't reduce me to a "bot" who subs PC words while meaning the same.

Comment: @Harper I read the pre-edit answers and it didn't seem that way to me. I think other people were reading between the lines and seeing something that wasn't there. The point that people's spending habits would remain the same if they aquired a windfall is a perfectly valid one. Anyone who read that as "poor people are thick and they don't help themselves" is being just absurd.

Answer (score 20):

In 2013, the [average checking account balance](https://www.valuepenguin.com/banking/average-checking-account-balance) was US \$9,132. That's personal accounts, not business or government accounts. But for people with an income above US \$160,000 / year, the average balance was over US \$700,000. Again, personal, not business. For those with incomes below US \$45,000, the bank balance was below \$3,600.

Given that many large business accounts will have significantly higher balances than the average citizen, and that the wealth distribution is heavily weighted, I suspect the lowest income people will see a rise in bank balance, while those at the highest income levels will see a drop. Those in the middle of that bell curve will have the most randomness to their balances.

But really, the new balances don't matter, as we'll explore below. **What matters is the introduction of chaos...**

### Immediate term

**You are going to have serious problems.** Day 1, CNN, Fox News, BBC, and all other news outlets flood the airwaves and papers with news that all the bank accounts got mixed around in a big melting pot.

So everyone lines up at the bank. Or logs into the bank. The bank's websites crash, as they're now effectively suffering a [DDoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) as users flood their sites. The lines will be long. The bank support phone numbers will be jammed. Panic.

This will continue for a time. In the USA, the federal government will probably institute an [emergency bank holiday](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/12/7.3000). Not sure how long that would last, but during this holiday, the banks would be doing their best to restore from backups, find audit traces, etc. The bank computer systems have pretty thorough audit logs. Banks would spend days, possibly weeks, trying to reconstruct accounts. The OP says these measures will fail, but they would try. Other nations' banks would go through similar steps.

The FBI, NSA, CIA, and similar groups in other countries would go on extremely high alert. I suspect the military would go on high alert as well, at least until it could be proven that this wasn't an act of cyberwar.

Hopefully, governments and businesses would find some sort of interim solution for commerce, because otherwise, *people will die*. Pharmaceutical companies, food and agriculture, these are critical international markets that if they stop, people don't survive. Remember, most industrialized nations cannot grow enough food to feed their people reliably, year round. So many import food from around the world. Especially produce. That's how we get out-of-season crops.

Then there are cities. It took 200,000 flights to provide Berlin with food and supplies for a year during the [Berlin Blockade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Blockade). *Now imagine every city in the world facing the need to feed and supply their citizens* when no one can pay for the shipment of any goods. No one can pay for trucking or trains. No cargo ships full of Argentina apples. No meat from out west delivered to your local butcher. Everyone goes hungry. No insulin for your diabetics; who's paying for that? Everyone gets sick or sicker.

*If food and medicine deliveries aren't secured, then the riots tear apart every city in the world*. And if that happens, no nation will survive. So that's a crisis that governments and industry must solve immediately or die. The rest of this post assumes they hobble together something. Anything else results in anarchy.

### Short term

**After the banks close, people will panic.** News cycles would probably be fueling the panic. Comparisons to the bank collapses around the Great Depression would be constant.

No one can issue paychecks. No one can pay their bills. No one can do anything if they don't have cash on hand. By day 2 or 3 at the latest, the stock markets would be shut down, since businesses no longer have reliable checking accounts either. The markets would have to be shut down to prevent a complete collapse as everyone tries to sell and cash out.

Without paychecks and other cash transactions, trade halts. Government would need to do something to maintain food availability, since most people don't keep enough cash to buy groceries and few people maintain sufficient food supplies to go more than a week or two.

Emergency measures would be taken to prevent riots. There would be riot-gear equipped police in all major cities and many smaller cities/towns.

Everyone would be asking questions. Who, why, how. Within a week, it would be clear that banks cannot fix this. It is a complete, hard, reset on the entire economy.

### Medium term

By this time, it would be clear that while some accounts in some cases could be rebuilt from paper records, **the system as a whole couldn't be rebuilt.** And once people said, "Well, I've got my bank statements going back 10 years, *give me my money!"* everyone else would demand their money, too. And at least some percentage of people would think they were clever enough to game the system. "I've got a good printer and enough computer savvy to fake my bank statements..." so now the banks can't really trust the statements to be accurate either. That lack of reliable paper combined with the significant percentage of people without paper records, means banks as a whole cannot trust any of the papers anywhere.

Remember, this isn't just your grandmother's savings account or your checking account. This is also the account your employer writes paychecks from. This is where your rent checks deposit to. This is where your grocery store pays it's bills from.

By now, all of the initial panics are done. Banks will still be closed, at least until government figures out what to do. Barter is more popular than ever in living memory. The riots will have been quashed, one way or another. More cities across the world look like the burned out parts of post-riots Detroit than ever since the end of WW2.

The entire world economy has ground to a halt at this stage. No one has the means to pay for anything. Suddenly the Amish, with cash in hand and plenty of garden space, look far wiser than they have in the last 200 years. Doomsday preppers have been laughing this whole time, while they choke down freeze-dried food that's edible but tastes bad.

Congress will be under extreme pressure to **"do something".** And maybe they will. They must. Though at least in the USA, partisanship politics will make this a difficult time for them as well. At a global level, the UN will be frantically trying to prevent war and economic collapse, too.

If the UN cannot maintain peace between panicked member states, or if any one (or more) nation decides that the other nations somehow are responsible for this mess, then war will break out. Hopefully, these will be relatively small-scale actions in smaller nations. Hopefully, the warfare won't spread up to the 2nd and 1st world nations. But that's not guaranteed. Wars generally occur for three reasons: "the gods demand it", "we need money/resources/things", and "if THEY are the enemy then you won't get mad at how horrible a leader I am". This event triggers the second quite easily and quite suddenly.

Government would have to write laws, too, that prevented civil lawsuits. Otherwise, the courts would be overrun with lawsuits and class-action lawsuits. If those cases were permitted, lawyers would be lining up. Any bank that wasn't already ruined beyond repair would be destroyed.

### Long term

Long term, the major goal is to **reduce this great depression and prevent global war.** A broken nation with no economy and no hopes will often fall into warfare. It's happened before (see also Nazi Germany, which "solved" their unemployment crisis through military spending). Given the scope of this disaster, it would likely happen here. WW3 isn't impossible. It's likely.

Some governments will have nationalized their banks to take control and restore order. Perhaps they socialize the wealth and redistribute it. Perhaps they start over with some other measure. There's no way to predict how each nation will solve this crisis.

But once they do solve it, we will see some kind of major sea-change to how accounting is done. No one will ever trust banks to maintain account histories and balances ever again. This new system will be the most radical rewrite to bookkeeping / accounting since the invention of [double-entry bookkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system#History).

Comment: *"Well, I've got my bank statements going back 10 years, give me my money!"* I'm not sure that it necessarily follows that this would be impossible. Remember, the OP's premise is that the accounts are all there; only the mapping from account to account holder is scrambled. Presumably then, transaction histories are intact. If you have papers going back ten years, and those match the bank's records, why would those not be usable as proof that you at least have some rights to the account? Especially if you've got (possibly multiple) photo IDs matching the names involved. Ingenuity shall prevail?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Give me a bank statement, my home PC and scanner, and half a day. I can have a bank statement that will match the original (assuming it's on the same paper size) except it will show a significantly different bank balance.

Comment: @CM_Dayton Sure, but will it match the bank's records for the specified account?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I've tightened up that beginning. Should be clearer what I was trying to say.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, the bank's records don't mean anything. "My paper PROVES I have a bazillion dollars!" I say. Bank says "our records prove that someone had some money... somewhere." And now it goes to court. And there, the proof is.... useless.

Comment: Added some more about courts and food/medicine.

Comment: @CM_Dayton that's a looooot harder than it sounds.  Also the government may just say "Hup, every citizen  who can prove he has an account gets \$5000 and every corporation gets \$FORMULA_HERE based on surviving tax data, that's a loan, and we'll square it when able."  It would be better for the economy  to lump the additional national debt than the economic catastrophe discussed in this answer.

Comment: Yes, that's an entirely reasonable action by government. And one that would result in some foaming-at-the-mouth anger by anyone who's personal wealth had been greater than that amount. I'm not saying it couldn't work. Just that it would still get ugly. Ugly enough to lead to attempted coups in at least some cases.

Comment: Wars generally occur for three reasons: "the gods demand it", "we need money/resources/things", and "if THEY are the enemy then you won't get mad at how horrible a leader I am". This event triggers the second quite easily and quite suddenly.

Comment: +1 Exactly this. Peoples actions will first and foremost be determined by [loss aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion). That bank run will definitely happen. If only to check whether todays lottery gave me a filled bank account so that I can quickly withdraw it all.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO.  A very engaging read.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I'm not sure about a couple of things. Why would the police be doing anything? They're not being paid anymore. Same for Congress and the rest of the government. Certainly some people have a call to serve, but enough of them? And even those who do - if they have to protect themselves and their family, how many will choose society over that?

Comment: In the comments on another answer it came up that if this is worldwide (and if God understands exchange rates, I guess), then besides being a transfer of "wealth" from corporate accounts to random poor citizens, it would (on average) momentarily transfer "wealth" from the First World to other nations. Would this generate any interesting subplot, or would it not matter because in the "Immediate Term" all the relevant banks fail and the old currency becomes worthless?

Comment: I'm with @michaelkjorling on this, it would take less than a few months for a decent set of programmers to come up with ways of scanning people's bank statements and using that to identify the account that belongs to that person. It would take a while to get through them all, but once the obvious candidates have been identified you'll have a reasonable chunk of the system back. Eventually you'll be left with accounts that are harder to identify and you'll need to switch to detective work.

Answer (score 12):

What follows is complete social collapse. If it can happen once, it will quite likely happen again, so there is no longer any point in saving or investing. So no companies can be funded, no one has money for their retirement, and so on and so forth.

Comment: You may want to review this answer in light of the OP's recent edit.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I don't agree. Poor people often don't have much in the way of savings in a bank account at any one time, so they can only benefit from the change. The people with significant, valuable assets (property) are also those with larger bank accounts. On average, someone poorer will end up with the richer account, but someone rich may still have assets to keep going.

Comment: `no longer any point in saving` You could still physically store your money or buy things with inherent value (e.g., gold) and hold onto that. `or investing` I do agree with that though.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I see your point, although the money being unavailable is a scenario which isn't established in the question or this answer. It's a reasonable point of discussion for its own answer.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin seriously? They limited bank withdrawals in Greece?  That defeats the entire concept of "your money" and basically removes all incentive for people to create and innovate.  Can someone send them copies of Atlas Shrugged? All they really do is murder domestic banking and your fiat currency - everyone goes BitCoin or USD.   That would never be tolerated in the US, and the last time it was, Great Depression.  Going into natonal debt so FDIC could cover provable losses ( up to their standard $250k) is the way to go.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin  I believed *you*.   I just can't believe *them* (in the metaphorical meaning of "can't believe".) What were they thinking LOL!

Answer (score 11):

[CM_Dayton's amazingly detailed answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/88365/10048) is spot-on, IMHO, and covers a lot of the societal aspects. As someone who reads a lot of rationalist sci-fi, though, I have to point out one inevitable subplot:

> However, other than your memories and environment (e.g. you're in a mansion, so probably were doing ok...), there is no way to prove which balance was previously yours. Backup data has also been altered to be consistent. Every detail apart from the associated names is accurate. If account 123 sent money to account 456, that's still recorded, but account 123 probably belongs to someone other than expected.

This sounds like a perfect use-case for [traffic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_analysis). All we need is a complete set of banking records and a few smart programmers, and we can start crunching the numbers and restoring the state of the world by building outward from a trusted root. Thus:

> Bob is the security engineering lead for Chase Manhattan. On Tuesday morning, he wakes up to the ringtone that means a critical production issue. (This is unusual, because Bob is like the third person in the PagerDuty escalation. Things *never* escalate to him unless the site is actually down or something.)
>
> Well, crap. Nonsense in the banking records. The automatic disaster-recovery plan was already tried, and somehow the backups are wrong too. (Everyone on the engineering team is confirming: their own balance is definitely incorrect.) Okay, check the tape archives. Somehow they're *also* bad. Now it's getting surreal.
>
> 90 minutes later. The site is "down for maintenance" to prevent *further* chaos. Jan and Dan (and about three junior engineers that nobody cared to forbid) are in a breakout room whiteboarding new ideas. Bob is finally en route to the office, on a call with about three VPs. Nobody knows where Legal is. Someone go pull a junior engineer out of the brainstorming session and get them to make sure Legal is in PagerDuty by EOD, okay?
>
> 120 minutes. Dave (who's always been a bit rogue — regulations shmegulations) has written a script to scan all the accounts and locate the ones with balances in a given range, and is going desk to desk asking if anyone remembers *exactly* how much money was in their account yesterday. Pretty soon he has a couple of hits; some people have the app and look at their balance like the rest of us check Facebook.
>
> There are still millions of accounts that could be theirs. This is going to be tough. But Maria says she's got direct deposit on her rent — now we're cooking! (Jan and Dan are still holed up in the breakout room, but we can see the left half of the board is full of abstract graphs and the right-hand side is a list something like "paycheck / rent / credit card / big-ticket / ...") Twenty minutes later, Dave has v2 of his script. It finds Maria's $1035.21 rent payment in a flash. One down!
>
> In fact, two down, because we also now know the identity of Maria's landlord. (Well, somewhat. His name is John something? He lives down in Gilroy. Never seen him. But we can get him on the phone if we need to.)
>
> Dave uses his script on Rick's direct-deposit paystub. (Normally Rick would have an aversion to revealing his salary, but today isn't "normal". Normally *Dave* would *love* to reveal everyone's salary. He's having a ball right now.) Now we have Rick and Maria. This is going great! And Rick says he paid Dan for lunch the other day, it was like $20, so if they can see that payment they'll know which account is Dan's... oh. Hmm. Rick paid Dan with Venmo. So it happened entirely within the Venmo app, and won't be reflected in anyone's Chase balance. Bother. Venmo — and credit cards in general — are going to make this a lot harder than if everyone paid by check all the time!

Here I'm out of my depth and so I'll stop with the details, but hopefully Jan and Dan will come up with something. Jan has some contacts at Netflix; maybe their billing system is still unscrambled, in which case we can resolve a lot of accounts by looking at the timing of their monthly $7.99 payments. (Or whatever it is now. Jan does *not* have the Chase app.)

I predict that within an hour, Bob and Dave and Accounting will have the ability to shuffle the corporate accounts back into place. Within 24 hours, Dave's "Rentinator" (sorry, "Whiscash"? Why does everything need a code name around here?) will be crunching through the accounts for every employee. However, it will take several days to actually *apply* the changes, unless Bob's team has been foresighted enough to allow "duplicating" the production system. After all, we don't want to shuffle things on the *real* production system; that's going to be on lockdown for *days*, until we figure out whether there's anything Forensics can do with it, and until Legal tells us we won't get in trouble for changing it. So one of the postmortem action items we can see already is that we ought to have a way to test out Dave's script without modifying the production data. Put a couple of engineers on that.

Also, in the postmortem we always ask "Are we still vulnerable?" In this case the answer is obviously yes; we have no idea what caused the initial scrambling. But *transactions* were neither blanked nor scrambled; that's how we managed to unscramble everything. And merchant records — amounts, and names, and shipping addresses — seemed to be okay. So there's something kind of "magic" about lossy representations of transaction history. How fast can we start keeping our *own* redundant lossy record? No reliance on account-UIDs; those get scrambled. But we can store personal names, and street addresses; that'll be good enough for most people. And you know what? Throw in a column with the salted SHA-256 hash of their account-UID. If *those* get scrambled "correctly" next time, then at least we'll know someone up there can break SHA-256.

And if it never happens again, hey, problem solved. :)

Comment: I should point out that the (fictional) SRE team's reaction in this story encodes the implicit assumption that when something goes wrong, the best thing to do is *put it back the way it was*. Nobody really even considers whether we should redistribute the money another way. This was a failure of *our company's* record-keeping system, so it's up to us to *repair it*. (The fact that every other bank is also down today is out of our control and doesn't affect our optimal response, just our degree of schadenfreude.)

Comment: This story also assumes that our bank's records got scrambled among themselves, not with other banks' records (whatever that would even *mean*, given the different database schemas involved). If doing the traffic analysis requires cooperation among every bank in the world, from Chase Manhattan to Podunk S&L to the Bank of Nigeria, I admit it's hopeless.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer I consider only the shuffle itself: others are talking about the fallout, and in any case you seem to have edited your question with the intent of removing the longer-term effects on society from consideration.

> I suspect there will be a bias towards getting poorer, with a few stand out 
>   cases of someone getting immensely rich.

It's correct that there are a few standout cases of someone getting immensely rich, since there are relatively few accounts with immense amounts of money in them (relative to the number of people, I mean). But it's more likely than (say) winning the lottery, since there are more big acounts in the banking system than lottery draws in a lifetime. There will also be some big losers who are randomly assigned an account that's more overdrawn than their entire other assets, and become overnight bankrupts. So it goes.

If by "there will be a bias towards getting poorer" you meant, "there's less money on average than before", then perhaps counter-intuitively I think that's probably true. The reason is there are large numbers of abandoned accounts (which somebody owns, but they've forgotten about them, or died and the estate failed to claim them, or otherwise are uncontactable), and I speculate that those abandoned accounts on average have small amounts of money in them. Of course this speculation might be wrong (in the real world and/or your world), in which case this effect is non-existent or is reversed, but supposing it is correct:

After the shuffle, abandoned accounts will on average (in all probability) have (approximately) average amounts of money in them, which is more than small amounts. Since the population of abandoned accounts increases in value, it follows that the population of active accounts will reduce in value. Of course, *eventually* the banks (or someone else) will reclaim this money provided that the law grants a mechanism for abandoned accounts eventually to be harvested, but the eventual recipient can't put it on their books immediately because they don't know which accounts it is.

If we ignore forgotten/lost accounts, and futher simplify by assuming that every person has exactly one account, then the total (and hence mean) bank balance of course stays the same. But what about the number of people who get richer vs. the number who get poorer?

To address this, line everyone up in order of bank balance. You will be randomly assigned a new position in line: if you move left then you get poorer, if right then richer (I simplify: in fact a significant number of people have equal balances, and so likely a few will see no change. For what it's worth, the probability that at least one person gets their own original account right back is approximately 63.2%, or 1 - 1/e, where e is Euler's constant). It should be obvious that if you're 75% of the way up the line, then you have a 75% chance of getting poorer and a 25% chance of getting richer. The *amount* by which you become richer or poorer is irrelevant to which of the two happens. Meanwhile, the next person up has a 75.00000001% chance of getting poorer and a 24.99999999% chance of getting richer, and so on. Add it all up along the line, and *on average* everyone has a 50% chance of getting richer and a 50% chance of getting poorer. The number of winners and the number of losers will with high probability be approximately the same: 50/50 (well, OK, 50-ε/50-ε of richer/poorer, and 2ε of staying the same, where ε is some small number). Of course it's *possible*, but incredibly improbable, that the shuffle selected moves everybody left one place except the person on the far left, who moves to the far right. So almost everyone gets poorer. Similarly it's possible for the reverse rotation to occur, so almost everyone gets richer. But these are vanishingly unlikely to occur at random.

In short: if you shuffle a deck of cards then by symmetry there's no overall bias in favour of more cards moving upwards than move downwards. This remains true even if instead of the cards being evenly spaced, we space them according to the same distribution as bank balances, because whether a card moves up or down doesn't depend on the spacing between the cards, only on whether the new position is greater or less than the old position.

If you're just wondering about humans getting richer, as opposed to "legal people": I speculate that the median corporate balance is higher than the median human balance, in which case there is a slight bias for humans to get richer and corporations to get poorer (at least, prior to the knock-on effects which mean people who own shares in the corporations that get poorer, ultimately get poorer too). But it depends to an extent what we mean by "balance". Business accounts can have overdraft facilities, but to stretch a point you might also include short-term loans or bridging loans analogous to overdraft facilities. It might turn out that my speculation is incorrect (in the real world and/or your world), and corporations in fact *don't* have higher than median balances. I'm pretty sure they have higher-magnitude than average balances, but perhaps often the balance is massively negative. So again, if my speculation is incorrect then the bias disappears or reverses.

You could also consider what happens where people have multiple accounts. For example, for stupid reasons I have 4, 2 of them with very low positive balances. Therefore I get 2 extra shots at the jackpot. But I suspect that as it happens, the mean of my 4 balances is still above the global mean, and so my expected gain is negative.

Answer (score 3):

People will no longer trust banks, money becomes useless as a means of paying for goods and services as it has no value.

People fall back to systems of barter for services and goods.
Maybe some will accept valuables in trade for services, which they then trade on for other goods and services.

In time banking will reappear, but only hard records, written on paper, will be acceptable as proof of ownership of anything.

Which brings us to the linked implication, which is that any computerised system will be viewed with extreme suspicion.
It is quite likely a large part of the population will demand a complete ban on computers, maybe even a complete ban on any electronic equipment, because they're afraid of them (many people already are, this would give them an excuse).

Comment: You may want to review this answer in light of the OP's recent edit.

Comment: Sounds like the Butlerian Jihad.  (If you haven't read Dune, it's part of the backstory—a war which was fought, the outcome of which is that all "thinking machines" of any sort are totally banned.)

Comment: @Wildcard now that you mention it... But it's not uncommon in post-apocalyptic fiction to have similar themes of course.

Answer (score 3):

There are great answers here, way more interesting to read than mine, but they seem to miss the actual question asked:

> What would the overall change in wealth distribution [be]?

From a purely mathematical viewpoint, the change would be ... absolutely nothing.  It would have to be.

Visualize all the balances of all the bank accounts sorted like a bar graph, with the balances along the Y axis, and the names of all the account holders as data points along the X axis.

That bar graph represents "wealth distribution" literally.  All the money, and how it is distributed between people and businesses

The magic happens, and all the names are shuffled under the bar graph, leaving the balances alone.  The distribution is identical, by definition.

I think the other answers about the social consequences are much more interesting to consider, but in answer to the question asked, the *distribution* doesn't change.

[Edit 1 - addressing comments to both my answer, and the original question]

Original question has been clarified that this isn't all your wealth in a global ledger, just strictly bank accounts, with other assets untouched.  As such, I'll augment my answer here with an expansion of the comment I added to the main question.

For bank balances, if like our world, the distribution is a "long tail" graph, or tall pyramid. Many more folks/businesses (in number) have a "below average" (where "average" = mathematical mean) balance due to the few, very, very, high balances. The very few high balance accounts will end up worse off, but the many low ones could change relatively little, or even all go up. It won't be a "half less and half more" split unless the original distribution is balanced.

For example, you could have balances of 1,2,3,4,5,1000 - rotate each owner 1 account to the right. 5 of the 6 people get more money, and only 1 loses (a lot) of money.

Or you could have originally, balances of 1,2,3,1000, and 100 more accounts all at 100 each.  In this case, the majority of accounts end up with exactly the same balance (and different payment histories) and only a few people get more and less.

I think my answer still holds.  the overall distribution doesn't change (by definition) and under most reasonable assumptions of the shape of that distribution before the incident, most folks don't substantially change, with a few dramatic outliers.

Comment: I'm not sure... If you have assets in terms of property, expensive cars, luxury yachts and so on, that wealth remains yours. Likewise, if you keep everything in cash, still yours. It's just the nebulous banked money which moves, after all.

Comment: Sure, but OP wasn't specific about other sources of wealth in this hypothetical world. From the form of the question, I'm assuming "bank account" was meant to encompass primary stores of wealth, and the focus of the question want meant to be limited to "just banks," but rather a sort of Global ledger of wealth.

Comment: I took the question to be about the distribution of the changes to people's balances (which of course is non-zero with probability almost equal to 1), not the change in the distribution of balances (which of course is zero as you explain).

Comment: @SteveJessop If the question is purely about the effect of permutations on distributions, it's off-topic here, anyway. That's mathematics, not world-building.

Comment: Nice that at least someone answers the actual question. Note that under the assumption that your bank account is positively correlated with other assets, reshuffeling accounts would actually make the distribution more even.

Answer (score 2):

Are things like credit cards affected? If not, then it isn't that bad.

Firstly, the real problem is that people only really keep money in their bank accounts to pay off debt. If that money increases, great. Otherwise, you have people unable to pay mortgages, utility bills, etc. Credit cards offer some relief **if** they are unaffected. Without them, you have individuals and businesses suddenly declaring bankruptcy, unable to pay employees and service providers.

Nobody is going to risk attempting repossession or debt recovery, but services will be stopped until bills are paid, since the service providers need to pay their own bills, but unless the services are up, people and businesses cannot work to get money to pay those bills, and so the cycle continues.

Secondly, while people who can afford to, keep most of their wealth in non liquid assets, they still have bills to pay. Once their ready cash stock disappears, they'll need to convert some of their wealth to cash--except that everyone who has wealth but needs cash will be doing the same. [The 1929 Stock Market crash](http://www.history.com/topics/1929-stock-market-crash) is an excellent case study of what happens next.

Thirdly, those fortunate few, who woke up, heard the news and rushed to the bank only to find themselves filthy rich, will fall into two groups. Group 1 will try to withdraw as much as they can before the mistake is corrected. The banks fearing a run will limit funds. This will result in more people trying to get their money while they can. The ones who do manage to get a sizeable sum will immediately become targets of everyone else, including law enforcement. If they manage to get home alive, they still won't be safe when people figure out where they live. Group 2 will have figured all this out and will only pay off their immediate debts through the bank then go home with only a small amount in cash.

Once the government figures out what is going on, mainly through their own accounts suddenly emptying, the most likely response will be an excise on any amount over a certain floor. This will outrage the lunatic right and the army will have to be mobilised. The major advantage the government has, is that it can print cash, can pay off most of its immediate debt. The rest will vary from country to country: some might end up in civil war, others in long depressions; one outcome of the 1929 crash was the rise of Nazism.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the overall change in wealth distribution?

This is a statistical question well-suited for [**Cross Validated**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). The actual "change" in the nature of *wealth distribution* would depend on the nature of the utilised [*univariate distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univariate_distribution) that would be used to derive the new random account balance figures. For instance, [platykurtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) distribution would be likely to reduce average differences between single account balances, assuming that the pre-existing distribution was leptokurtic (more likely).

You could look at a number of existing household income / affluence surveys, and construct casual statical models replacing likely existing account values with random ones and assess how that change impacts the overall *"wealth distribution"* derived from the utlisied data set.